# Emulator doesnt show created app Android Studio

Tags: android

Code shows no errors, and when I try to run the emulator it runs with no error, but when it loads created app doesn't show up.

These are lines that showed up in debugger while emulator is running.

**HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentere**

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can cause the app not to be installed on your emulated device is if the emulator is running an API below your minimum supported. Try checking the build.gradle file in your src folder for this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

And compare that to your emulator API.

Also check that you've included an intent filter in your manifest under your main activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```